# How can I measure the performance and bottlenecks of my Tomcat Server?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, monitoring, jmx

I use Tomcat 7.0.42 in production and I have the problem that my server crashes 2-3 times a day. I could not figure out why. Is there a measurement tool that I can use to analyze my server performance?

Answer (score 0):

While the question is too broad and should be probably addressed on `serverfault` than on `stackoverflow`, here is what I would check first to see what's happening on the server.

1. Logs - check out any exceptions in `/var/log/tomcat7` (and errors like OutOfMemory). Check also if you have enough space on the disk.
2. Make sure your tomcat is running with `-server` option
3. Just to see the big picture you can use [JavaMelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide?tm=6#Setup) which is pretty much easy to install. If you use Maven, just add `javamelody-core` dependency and update your `web.xml` with

   ```
   <filter>
          <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
          <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <listener>
          <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```

   and then access your application with `http://<host>:<port>/<context>/monitoring`
4. If you notice for example, that memory is constantly growing and the limit is reached, may be you will need to increase JVM maximum heap size but may be there is a memory leak. In case of memory leak you will need to analyse/compare heap dumps with tools like `VisualVM`, `JProfiler`, `YourKit` etc.
5. I would also check other processes on the same server like sshd (with `netstat`) and also just to see general health `atop` or `htop`